# Array returning [Object object] instead of value?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Json Returning [object object] instead of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620953/json-returning-object-object-instead-of-array)

I have an array that contains a sub-array, being pulled via a POST request to a PHP file. The thing is, I am having a hard time finding how to return the value of the array objects, let alone iterate through it.

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php.php',
    data: 'id=testdata',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result[0]); // returns [Object object]
    },
});
```

I am sure that it is properly grabbing the array from the PHP file.

Here's [the PHP file](http://adventurelobbies.com/php.php).

Comment: what did you expect it to result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620953/json-returning-object-object-instead-of-array

Answer (score 4):

In your case, `result` is an array of objects, so `result[0]` is the first object. To access the `id` for example, you would use `result[0]['id']`. In order to iterate through the array of objects, you can use a for loop like this for example:

```
for(var i=0, len = result.length; i<len; i++) {
    //write your code for each object in the results here
    var id = result[i]['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must specify in your object, wich one to show, i mean....

```
alert(result[0]['field_name']);
```

As you are using PHP to fetch some data from one '**id**', I could advice you that when quering mysql, use the next syntax,

```
echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query('your_query')));
```

With this syntax you will get only one object with all the fields fetched in your query, so the alert would be:

```
alert(result['field_name']);
```

I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over it like:

```
$.each(result, function () {
    alert(this.name);   // or this.id, this.description, etc.
});
```

I recommend using a tool such as Firebug, then doing `console.log(result);` to get a more descriptive output.